# How to change backgrond-color of any website page through url?

Tags: css

I am facing a problem related to  css.My question is that I want to change background-color to black of any website page through url. I want this for study better to protect my eyes meanwhile I have eye problem. So what code to apply in the url to show the page black meanwhile we use this css rule like body **{
background-color:#00000;}** to output .I have attached two images for it to clear more better.Hope will get response as soon as possible.Thank you too much!
[image]
[image]

Comment: You could use a $_get in php then dynamically change it in JS.

Comment: You can't do this through the URL.  You can create custom user stylesheets in Firefox, for one possibility.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3074592/laaposto brother doctor is not the solution here I use the computer whole day.Doctor can not protect it!

Comment: If you change the background color black you are going to need other css to turn the text white

Comment: Sir,My question is that can I do it with the help of css or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution for you to it to take some of the recommendations above, and turn it into a bookmarket! That way, you can always click the button in your address bar and it will

1) Load jQuery if necessary
2) Change the background-color of `<html>` and `<body>` elements to black.

Here's a link to the JSFiddle. Drag the link to your bookmarks bar and watch the magic happen:
http://jsfiddle.net/lasha/GjQGZ/

No need for all the extra steps! :)

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it manually step by step .I can not understand what to do with jsfiddle

Comment: Sure, first, follow the instructions on this page to enable your bookmarks bar: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarks-toolbar-display-favorite-websites

Then, open the JSFiddle page I linked to and drag the blue link that says "Run jQuery Code" into the bookmarks bar that you now see.

Then, click it, and you should see the background color change!

Comment: This yourtube video show you the concept of how to drag a link INTO the bookmarks bar. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-E6h7Z5fPlg

Answer (score 2):

you can't do it through a URL. However, since you're using firefox:

[image: change background in firefox]

Alternatively, look in to a plugin like greasemonkey (or similar) and inject custom CSS styles on to the page you're viewing. Something like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Readability Helper
// @description makes font more readable for custom viewing.
// @namespace   CSS
// @include     *
// @version     1.0
// ==/UserScript==

(function(w){
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = "* {color:#fff !important;background-color:#fff !important";
  w.document.body.appendChild(css);
})(unsafeWindow);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use some kind of glare reduction/warmer color software, like [F.lux](http://justgetflux.com/).

I use it and even with white backgrounds, my eyes don't get tired as much.

Answer (score 2):

For SO site, where Jquery is used, you can type this in the console:

```
$('body').css('background-color', '#000');
```

And also you can change the text color to white:

```
$('body').css('color', '#fff');
```

If no Jquery is loaded, you can selet the body tag with document.getElementByTagName

Comment: I find `document.body` easier than using the `get*` methods. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Brad already gave a good answer.

Alternatively you could use the Firefox add-on [Color That Site!](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/color-that-site/)

*The purpose of this Add-on is to let you easily change the colors of any web site you want. These color edits can be permanently saved and be im-/exported for sharing.*

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by applying some javascript to the site. After site is loaded, you can write in the address bar something like this:

```
javascript:document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
```

Make sure to include 'javascript:' prefix part (if you copy/pasted it might happen that browser excluded it for security reasons).

**This will work only locally, of-course!**

UPDATE: If it happen for some reason this doesn't work in chrome, try to do it like this:

```
javascript:document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000"; alert()
```

I didnt figure why or how but it works!

Comment: Can you explain how to put in the url ? I put it like stackoverflow.comjavascript:document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000"; not working!

Comment: This is not possible due to security reasons. You cannot do that. Imagine what else can you do in javascript, you would put any kind of malicious code to any site. Users wouldn't recognize change in the url. This is why this is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such things with a URL (unless the server specified in the URL has special functionality for this).

You can use a user style sheet or browser add-on to impose your CSS rules. The ways to do such things depend on browser.

When using a user style sheet, you mostly need the `!important` specifier, since by default page (author) style sheet rules override use style sheet rules. Example:

```
body { background: black !important;
       color: white !important; }
```

Note that this also overrides any background image that pages might set for `body`. And setting color whenever you set background is a good idea—you don’t want to see black on black, or even dark gray on black.

But it’s really more complicated. Any element can have a background (and content color) of its own. For example, if a page has `<body><div id=content>...</div></body>` and it sets background on that `div`, then you settings for `body` won’t have much effect.

At the extreme, you could replace `body` by `*` in the rule above, to make *everything* white on black, except those ingredients that are not under CSS control (like contents of images and possibly some form fields).